# How to update textblock with method

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, real-time

I have a textbox that provide user to input string. how can i pass that string to method and toUpper() it. and pass back the string to textblock in the main window that both of the box and block update in real time?

For my C# code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
private  void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        textBlock.Text = textBox.Text +"changed";
        
        
    }
```

it is just as simple like this.

for my xaml code:

```
<Grid >
    
   
    <TextBox x:Name ="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" Margin="28,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HELLO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="114,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
</Grid>
```

i want to know why the text of my textblock cannot be updated when i type something inside the textbox.

Comment: Textbox to Upper , and use this text in other form ,is this correct .What code do you have now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined the answer of @Yavor Georgiev

You are encountering a null reference exception. When the textBox control is created it will trigger the textChange event on textBox and by that point, textBlock isn't created and is therefore null. You can just change the order of the textboxes in the XAML and you will be fine.

Change the order

```
Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="114,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
    <TextBox x:Name ="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" Margin="28,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="HELLO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
   
</Grid>
```

For the upper part i used @Yavor Georgiev answer when typing

```
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text?.ToUpper();
        textBlock.Text = textBox.Text;
        textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text?.Length ?? 0; 
        textBlock.Text = textBox.Text + "changed";           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
private  void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text?.ToUpper();
        textBlock.Text = textBox.Text;
        textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text?.Length ?? 0; //You need this to continue typing from the last index onwards..
        
    }
```

I don't exactly understand if you need both the `textBox` and the `textBlock` to change at the same time or only the `textBlock` to be in `UpperCase`, but the concept is the same

Comment: i used your code in the answer @Yavor Georgiev

Comment: @Bas H That's perfectly fine... I didn't notice the Null reference exception because I didn't set the Text properties in the XAML (in my test case). :)

Comment: Any updat on this question , did you solved it.